# Compiler Error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, iphone

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CFMakeCollectable", referenced from:
      -[ASIFormDataRequest encodeURL:] in ASIFormDataRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest startRequest] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest checkRequestStatus] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest readResponseHeaders] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyProxyCredentialsAndResume] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyCredentialsAndResume] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest handleStreamComplete] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      ...
  "_CFReadStreamCopyError", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest handleStreamError] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_CFReadStreamCopyProperty", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest checkRequestStatus] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest readResponseHeaders] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyProxyCredentialsAndResume] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest attemptToApplyCredentialsAndResume] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest handleStreamComplete] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_CFReadStreamHasBytesAvailable", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest handleBytesAvailable] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_CFReadStreamOpen", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest startRequest] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_CFReadStreamSetClient", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest startRequest] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest scheduleReadStream] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[ASIHTTPRequest unscheduleReadStream] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
  "_CFReadStreamSetProperty", referenced from:
      -[ASIHTTPRequest startRequest] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
      -[PFHTTPCommand scheduleInCurrentThread] in Parse(PFHTTPCommand.o)
```

I am getting this error when trying to build. Can someone point out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have your header file included but .m files are missing. Also, seems like you haven't posted your whole error list.

Usually this kind of problems appear when you don't include all the .m files into your Build Phases.